# change the order of bars on sas graph

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a macro that produce a graph as in image [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Twp.jpg). I want to change the order of bars to `Dev 201601 201602 201603 201604 201605` instead of 
`201601 201602 201603 201604 201605 Dev`. Here is my code

```
goptions reset=global gunit=pct border cback=white 
colors=(black red green blue) ftitle=swissb
ftext=ZAPFB htitle=5 htext=1.7
offshadow=(1.5,1.5);
axis1 label=none;
axis2 label=none value=none
order=(0 to 110 by 10)
major=none
minor=none;
legend1 cborder=black cblock=CXF0E68C label=none
shape=bar(3,3)
POSITION=(bottom center);
pattern1 color=vpapb;
pattern2 color=bigy;
pattern3 color=paoy;
pattern4 color=vligb;
pattern5 color=lipk;
pattern6 color=vpap;
pattern7 color=pab;
pattern8 color=lio;

proc gchart data= Recent.char_&value;
title ;
vbar Period / sumvar=Percent
subgroup=&value
inside=subpct
width=12
space=8
maxis=axis1
raxis=axis2
legend=legend1
cframe=BWH
coutline=black;
```

What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Could you please provide some universally working code with data so we can run it ourselves ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to have your bar value be an ordering value that you use a format to display as your actual value.  So here I have 0 = Dev, 1 = 201601, 2 = 201602, etc.; I use a picture format to get there since things work so nicely, but you could use a regular value format if there's not a simple logical mapping like this.

```
data test_data;
input period value; /* you may need to convert from '201601' to '1' if your data already has 201601 type values;  use an informat (opposite of format). */
datalines;
1 10
2 20
3 25
4 25
5 30
0 20
;;;;
run;

proc format;
picture periodF
0 = 'Dev'  /* map 0 to Dev */
1-12 = 99 (prefix='2016');  /* for values 1-12, display in 2 digit zero padded format, prefix with 2016) */
quit;

proc sgplot data=test_data;
  format period periodf.;    /*apply format here or in an earlier datastep */
  vbar period/response=value;
run;
```

Comment: It works, but now I encounter this problem, instead of 6 bars as it suppose to be, the graph now has only 5 bars ('dev' and 201601-201604, 201605 is not there anymore). Here is what I got in log:
"WARNING: There was not enough room to use the specified width of 12 and space of 8 for the bars.
WARNING: One or more bars in the VBAR chart of period1 were clipped to the range of the specified response axis."
How can I fix that?

Comment: I tried changing the width and space but it doesn't help. the bars got smaller, so is the frame and there were still only 5 bars.